# Delphi multi color value in TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want the currency values ​​in the TStringGrid table to have different color decimals. How can do that?

[image]

Comment: See f.i, the `OnDrawCell` event of TStringGrid, described in the Online Help..

Comment: i looked online help. but i didnt find any help for multi color grid canvas

Comment: @zuluman: That's because it is up to the programmer (i.e. you) to implement that yourself.

Comment: @Martyn if you allow me, I don't think the answer you refer to answers this question. The other one, although indicates where (`OnDrawCell`) to code, it specifically only concerns the background color. This question asks for color change of the text, and specifically the decimals of a value. As seen from the solution by @Andreas it is much more involved than painting the bg.

Comment: Thanks@TomBrunberg, I've re-opened it.  Obviously having a bad day.  (Btw, I'm sure there must have been a multitde of qs about this)

Comment: Thanks @MartynA for reopening. Not sure about multitude, there has been many concerning bg fill or fg text colors but not what I recall, concerning aligned (as naturally expected in this case) split of text colors. Also, Andreas solution is rather well done.

Comment: Yes, Andreas's usually are.

Answer (score 4):

You need to draw the cells yourself by implementing an [`OnDrawCell`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnDrawCell) handler.

Something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Grid: TStringGrid;
  S: string;
  Val: Double;
  FracVal, IntVal: Integer;
  FracStr, IntStr: string;
  IntW, FracW, W, H: Integer;
  Padding: Integer;
const
  PowersOfTen: array[0..8] of Integer =
    (
      1,
      10,
      100,
      1000,
      10000,
      100000,
      1000000,
      10000000,
      100000000
    );
  Decimals = 2;
  BgColor = clWhite;
  IntColor = clBlack;
  FracColor = clRed;
begin

  Grid := Sender as TStringGrid;

  if (ACol < Grid.FixedCols) or (ARow < Grid.FixedRows) then
    Exit;

  Grid.Canvas.Brush.Color := BgColor;
  Grid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  S := Grid.Cells[ACol, ARow];
  Padding := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth('0') div 2;

  if not TryStrToFloat(S, Val) or not InRange(Val, Integer.MinValue, Integer.MaxValue) then
  begin
    Grid.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfLeft]);
    Exit;
  end;

  IntVal := Trunc(Val);
  IntStr := IntVal.ToString;
  if Decimals > 0 then
    IntStr := IntStr + FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator;
  IntW := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(IntStr);
  FracVal := Round(Frac(Abs(Val)) * PowersOfTen[Decimals]);
  FracStr := FracVal.ToString.PadRight(Decimals, '0');
  if Decimals = 0 then
    FracStr := '';
  FracW := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(FracStr);
  W := IntW + FracW;
  H := Grid.Canvas.TextHeight(IntStr);

  if W >= Grid.ColWidths[ACol] - 2*Padding then
  begin
    S := '###';
    Grid.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfRight]);
  end
  else
  begin
    Grid.Canvas.Font.Color := IntColor;
    Grid.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Right - Padding - W,
      Rect.Top + Rect.Height div 2 - H div 2, IntStr);
    Grid.Canvas.Font.Color := FracColor;
    Grid.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Right - Padding - FracW,
      Rect.Top + Rect.Height div 2 - H div 2, FracStr);
  end;

end;
```

This code will write non-numeric data left-aligned as is. For numeric data, it will draw the values with a fixed number of decimals. You can choose the decimals (0..8), as well as the colours of the integral and fractional parts. If the number doesn't fit in its cell, ### will be displayed instead.

[image: Screenshot of the grid with text and numbers.]

I haven't fully tested the code. I'll leave that to you as an exercise.

*Update:* Sorry, I forgot you are using Delphi 7. This means that you need to replace `IntVal.ToString` with `IntToStr(IntVal)` and so on.